# Verify if there is video signal in videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a project in which it plays *IPTV*. I would like to identify if there is video signal in order to show an alertdialog if there isn't signal. I could set a timer to wait for the signal to return, but I don't know how to identify if there is a signal or not. Could you please help me. I leave the code with which I am working. SdkVersion 22.

```
public class Television extends Activity {

VideoView videoView;
ImageView volmas, volmenos, voloff;
SeekBar seekbar;
TextView textview, tvvolumen;
AudioManager audioManager;
int i = 50;
int volumen = 7;
int volumenporcentaje;
Toast toast;
Exception e;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_television);

    try {
        String canal = getIntent().getStringExtra("Canal");

        volmas = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.volmas);
        volmenos = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.volmenos);
        voloff = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.voloff);

        tvvolumen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvvolumen);
        volumenporcentaje = (volumen * 100) / 15;
        tvvolumen.setText("" + volumenporcentaje + "%");

        e = null;

        videoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.videoViewTV);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(canal));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();

        voloff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                volumen = 0;
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volumen, 0);
                volumenporcentaje = (volumen * 100) / 15;
                tvvolumen.setText("" + volumenporcentaje + "%");
            }
        });

        volmas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (volumen < 15) {
                    volumen = volumen + 1;
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volumen, 0);
                    volumenporcentaje = (volumen * 100) / 15;
                    tvvolumen.setText("" + volumenporcentaje + "%");
                }
                if (volumen >= 15) {
                    Toast.makeText(Television.this, "Volumen al máximo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        volmenos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (volumen > 0) {
                    volumen = volumen - 1;
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volumen, 0);
                    volumenporcentaje = (volumen * 100) / 15;
                    tvvolumen.setText("" + volumenporcentaje + "%");
                }
                if (volumen == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Television.this, "Volumen al mínimo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        seekbar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volumen, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Errores.exception(e, this.getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to change your approach! Use [Exomedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) or [Exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) library. They are very simple.

Depend on your choice, you can use their function to solve your problem :)